# Is there a formula for finding the centers of the faces of a platonic solid?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is there a formula for finding the centers of the faces of a platonic solid given the center of the first (origin) face to be $P_0(x_0,y_0,z_0)$?

Comment: Given just the centrer of one face we cannot tell 1) which way it's turned and 2) how large it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the formula(coxeter) for the radius of the inner sphere of regular solids. the contact point of the plane of the face and the inner sphere is the center of that face.